# How to install kannada font in Android emulator

Tags: android, kannada

How to install Kannada fonts to emulator in Android to get Kannada keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

hi check this link it's not your perfect answer but some hint/idea for to you

http://www.android-devs.com/?p=33

ok no problem
download the fonts then in eclipse open the emulator on which you want to install the font
after opened go to the ddms and then in select emulator from device window now to related to that emulator you can see the detals like logcat, console etc in that tab was available "file explorer" select it. In that you see the dir select the sdcard and in same window at right top you see icon was enable like floppy and device type they are used for import and export file from pc to sdcard and viceversa now click on device icon using this you can import any file from pc to sdcard

Comment: Thanks for reply but its for Linux system not for windows

Comment: Link expects us to have root access to device :(
Is there any other way?